# Separating OAuth2 Authorization Server and Resource Server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I implementing OAuth2 Authorization Server and Resource Server.

and there are many documents told me
'Authorization Server and Resource Server can be Separated or not'

i like MSA, so i decided Separating these Servers.

i saw many documents in Internet about this issue, but i cant proceed anymore in practice.

i'm using SpringBoot2.

- Scenario

  1. User Connected to My `Client` Application.
  2. Request to secured endpoint `/client/me`
  3. in `Client`'s Controller, if user has not authenticated, redirect to `Authorization Server`'s login endpoint `/auth/oauth/authorize`.
  4. if user comes in my `Client` App first, user will sign-up(not sign-in) in my `Authorization Server`.
  5. in `Authorization Server`'s sign-up page, user will input his `username`, `realusername`, `password` and `email`.
  6. user's account has issued, and user will sign-in via my `Authorization Server`'s login form.
  7. if login succeed, `Client` will Request to `Resource Server`'s `/me` endpoint with `access-token`, and `Resource Server`'s Controller that mapped as `/me` will return `Principal` or `Authentication` Object as REST API.
  8. `Client` will bind there REST API's results into `DefaultOAuth2User` 
     or `CustomOAuth2User` in my `SecurityContext`.

here is question.

As far as I know, `Resource Server`'s `/me` endpoint will provide user's resources.
for example, realname or email etc.

but user has signed-up in `Authorization Server`, so all of information are saved in `Authorization Server`'s Database.

my oauth2 servers are MSA. so DB has been separated too.

then, how can i setting `email` or `realname` to `Principal` or `Authentication` or `CustomOAuth2User` Object via `Resource Server`'s `/me` endpoint?

Comment: When you say that the DBs are separate, what is in the Resource Server DB? I ask because it seems like you are saying that the `/me` endpoint, hosted by your resource server, doesn't have access to user data.

Comment: ResourceServer's DB will including '''userrealname''', '''email''', '''phone number'''.  but as i said how can i input these values in Db. becaues user will sign up in Authorization Server,   so these values will be included in authorization server db, not resource db.

Comment: i confused about resource and authorization servers responsibility.which server have to accept user signup process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Authorization Server is responsible for authenticating users or clients (other applications), checking if they are authorized to do what they want to do and on success, it issues a token. This means that a database it connects to should have all users credentials, clients IDs, clients secrets, roles, and other relevant information that helps in authentication and authorization.

Resource Server is responsible for handling all requests that came from frontend, be it authenticated requests or requests that are open (doesn't require authentication). Database it connects to should have information that is not relevant for authentication, like user's gender, height, weight, hobbies, etc.

To answer your question, you can create controllers in Resource Server that exposes registration, and other functionalities. This server will then make calls to Authorization Server. For registration, Resource Server will pass credentials to Auth Server to see if username is already claimed and if not register the user and based on the response of Auth Server, Resource Server will proceed with user registration. For login, frontend can make call to Auth Server directly to get token.

For all subsequent calls to protected resources (with access token) Resource Server would need to call Auth Server to verify tokens. For this Spring provides [CheckTokenEndpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/CheckTokenEndpoint.html) (`/oauth/check_token`).

You can also check [OAuth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html). This can be used in Resource Server for making REST requests to Auth Server. Note that Resource Server (or any other internal application that you have like frontend) will be clients for Auth Server. They would also need to authenticate and authorize themselves.

Comment: thx for your explaination with answer. very helpful. thank you !

Comment: @VijayNandwana - So are you suggesting that auth server will store username and password. Resource Server database will also need to store username, email and any other attributes that do not include password? So after resource server verifies the token with auth server's /oauth/check_token endpoint and if auth server returns success then resource server is expected to populate Principal object with information from resource server's database + what /oatuh/check_token endpoint returned and make it available in resource server's any protected endpoint (controller) that client makes calls to?

Comment: @itpragmatik - Yes that is correct. Instead of sharing username (between Auth & Resource server), its better to share UUID. You can create a filter chain in Resource Server to achieve this. Spring provides `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` that performs authentication and can extract OAuth2 token from the request, call Authentication Service, and populates the security context with the user info. Also, `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`, this wraps HTTP request into a security context aware request. this can supply Principal object to endpoints. Custom filter to populate user info.

Comment: Is it good to have one database for both authorization and resource servers or should we have different databases?

Comment: @Eniss I believe it isn't a problem to have one database, depends on your plan for the architecture. Otherwise, in a microservice view, I would prefer to separate those databases to guarantee individual adjustments and updates.

Comment: What can be done when the resource server needs to access information such as the roles of all users?

Comment: @Xlucxs Expose an endpoint in the Auth Service and call that endpoint from Resource Server.